# Understanding Self Join query

Tags: sql

This is my first post. Hope you can help me with this silly question:

I have this table with some ID car movements and its dates.

[image]

I need just the date interval between ID `'IN'` and ID `'OUT'`.

Here is my query and the outcome I get.

```
SELECT  
    T1.ID, T1.DATE_ID, T2.ID as ID_2, T2.DATE_ID AS DATE_2,
    DATEDIFF("D", T1.DATE_ID, T2.DATE_ID) AS DaysDiff
FROM    
    My database T1
JOIN 
    My database T2 ON T1.ID = 'IN' AND T2.ID = 'OUT'
WHERE 
    T1.DATE_ID >= '2017/01/01' AND T2.DATE_ID >= '2017/01/01'
GROUP BY 
    T1.ID, T1.DATE_ID, T2.ID, T2.DATE_ID 
ORDER BY
    DATE_ID
```

Output:

```
ID  DATE         ID_2       DATE_2       DaysDiff
-------------------------------------------------
IN  2017/02/15   OUT        2017/04/26    70
IN  2017/02/15   OUT        2017/10/05   232
IN  2017/04/26   OUT        2017/04/26     0        
IN  2017/04/26   OUT        2017/10/05   162
```

Question is, why I get the extra rows (second and third) and how do I dismiss them?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

seems you missed  the condition `T1.DATE_ID <  T2.DATE_ID`

```
SELECT  T1.ID, T1.DATE_ID, T2.ID as ID_2, T2.DATE_ID AS DATE_2,
        DATEDIFF("D", T1.DATE_ID, T2.DATE_ID) AS DaysDiff

FROM My database T1
JOIN My database T2 ON T1.ID = 'IN' 
        and T2.ID = 'OUT'

WHERE T1.DATE_ID >= '2017/01/01' and T2.DATE_ID >= '2017/01/01'
AND T1.DATE_ID <  T2.DATE_ID
group by T1.ID, T1.DATE_ID, T2.ID, T2.DATE_ID 
order by DATE_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I tried but:
[ID DATE        ID_2    DATE_2      DaysDiff
IN  2017/02/15  OUT 2017/04/26  70
IN  2017/02/15  OUT 2017/10/05  232
IN  2017/04/26  OUT 2017/10/05  162](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wv0Jy.jpg)

The right output should be:
[OUTPUT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6gKhh.jpg)
IN  2017/02/15  OUT 2017/04/26  70
IN  2017/04/26  OUT 2017/10/05  162